# Can not step into .NET framework source with VS2010 SP1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I followed steps in 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/07/12/step-into-net-framework-4-0-source-code.aspx to debug .Net framework source code but I can't step into the code of .net framework.

My .Net framework version is 4.0.30319 SP1 Rel, and I download .Net framework 4.0 source code from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Comment: The source code for .NET 4 is rapidly changing with lots of service releases and security patches.  They can't keep the source server updated.  This has been borken for a while now.