# Which reference source does include Microsoft.VisualBasic?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Microsoft lists a number of reference sources [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx). The [last blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rscc/archive/2010/08/16/net-framework-4-reference-source-is-available.aspx) lists `microsoft.visualbasic.dll` first, but I've dowloaded three likely candidates, renamed the downloaded file as an `.msi`, installed them and none have included the source for `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

Before I use up my monthly downloads, does anyone know if any current reference source includes `Microsoft.VisualBasic`?

(For me the download as you debug scenario now also fails for `Microsoft.VisualBasic` when it used to work, but I assumed that was just because I was stuck with VS2k8 and they'd "moved forward" as usual. I note the [existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10525139/256431) referring to this explains Microsoft is not keeping up with fixes, but for my purposes, any version would do.)

Comment: Good question but why not also ask it in a comment on that blog post you linked to?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Because this gets more responses. If Microsofties had responded to some of the more recent comments on that blog post I may have asked there. Also this should remain as an updateable answer as things change (if they do).

Comment: I've never seen source for Microsoft.VisualBasic included once.  Absence is impossible to prove positively, but pretty sure that list isn't accurate.

Comment: … why the hell did this get downvoted?

Comment: @HansPassant As I mention in the OP I definitely successfully did some runtime debugging with the VB.NET source when it was directly downloaded by VisualStudio 2008.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I got some slight serial downvoting across three questions where the other two make some sense.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this site](http://www.dotnetframework.org/Search.aspx) a while ago, with the source code to nearly (if not all) classes in the .NET Framework including comments and everything.

[This site](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/namespaces/53-Microsoft.VisualBasic) might also help, as it shows the classes and namespaces in a pretty easy to read format.

Comment: The first site looks very dodgy and doesn’t work. The second site works but uses the sources decompiled from IL, rather than the original sources.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're partially right. It doesn't seem to have any of the classes from the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace (at least none that I could find), but it seems to have the others.

Comment: The first site works fine for me (except the UI is a little screwy), but it is based upon one of the existing references sources, including the code duplication reported in the blog comments, and does not have the VB.NET sources. The second site is based upon a (poor compared to Reflector) decompile from IL (and it doesn't even show the `CInt` and `CLng` VB.NET casts that were the cause of my request (in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350588/why-roundfixx?lq=1)).

Comment: I edited this to change my downvote to an upvote, for the first link. It seems to contain ALL of the reference sources and does not show the VisualBasic types. This strongly suggests the current answer to my OP question is negative.

Comment: @MarkHurd Sort of unrelated, but I might also suggest [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) as an alternative to Reflector. It has the ability to open assemblies from GAC, and you can even view comments in the source code if you have the .PDB file; and for the built-in assemblies for the framework the program actually downloads it for you. And best of all, it's free!

Comment: @Banksy Your comment has caused me to actually download and try dotPeek, and although it does have some nice features, as a VB.NET programmer, not having a VB.NET decompile option pretty much means I won't use it. However, even ignoring the lack of VB.NET, the other major feature of free Reflector (which is what I still use) is the simple switch to IL to KNOW what the code is saying, even if the chosen decompilation is questionable or just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have not confirmed what is available for download now, but Microsoft have now made the reference source navigable, so e.g. `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` is here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic

Comment: NB This link now shows the "reference assembly" which has no code :-(